In C# how to I open a connection to a webbrowser and interact with it?
How do I establish an open connection to an open web browser in C#?
In a Microsoft C# program using a Visual Studio Code I am using the following namespaces:
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

After I get a string variable, "url", assigned with a URL of a website page, I use the following commands which successfully opens a browser window and loads the web site:
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

But this opens a chrome browser which is denoted somewhere as being a "test" session.  It somehow knows it was launched from a program.  And, since I am using this program to automate some interactions with linkedin, this information is passed along to linkedin which prompts me that it requires I login.  This creates a cascading seriies of events that are difficult to automate including using my cell as a means of verification.
So, instead of taking this route, how do I establish an open connection to an open web browser in C#?  I figure, if I instead connect to a web browser that is already open and already has its veriication steps done with linkedin, then I won't be prompted to log in and do any user verification.
On a personal note, if this is intentional security measures to prevent people from abusing a system, then this is a sad thing.
On a broader view, will all this mean I will have to make a web browser from scratch?
